# Parse Time in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to parse this date `Wed, 17 Feb 2021 13:00:00 +0100` into this `2021-02-17 13:00:00.000000000 +0100`.

And I've tried using this `Time.strptime(current_time.to_s, '%Q')`, (where `current_time` it's the date above) but I get `1970-01-01 01:00:02.021 +0100`

But I don't understand why I get another date, could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: It was a typo, my bad....I'll fix it!

Comment: You have `current_time.to_s` in your code. May I ask what kind of object `current_time` is? Chances are that you already have an instance of `Time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to parse this date `Wed, 17 Feb 2021 13:00:00 +0100` [...]

You seem to already have an instance of `Time`: (or `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` which is Rails' drop-in replacement with better timezone support)

```
current_time = Time.current
#=> Thu, 19 May 2022 10:09:58.702560000 CEST +02:00
```

In this case, there's nothing to *parse*. You just have to *format* it via [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html#strftime-method) the way you like:

```
current_time.strftime('%F %T.%N %z')
#=> "2022-05-19 10:09:58.702560000 +0200"
```

---

Parsing is only needed when you have a *string representation* that you want to turn into a `Time` object, e.g.: (using Rails' [`Time.zone.parse`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse) variant)

```
time_string = 'Thu, 19 May 2022 10:09:58.702560000 CEST +02:00'

time_obj = Time.zone.parse(time_string)
#=> Thu, 19 May 2022 10:09:58.702560000 CEST +02:00

time_obj.class
#=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```